# How to get array items one by one on Button click?

Tags: java, android

I am learning android studio, and I am a complete beginner. I have a textview and button on my activity, and i want that the textview takes strings from array in strings.xml and changes when i click the button.

I tried a for loop but it just gives one value and stops. 
This is the strings.xml file.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">myapp</string>

<string-array name="myarray">
    <item>Cow</item>
    <item>Pig</item>
    <item>Bird</item>
    <item>Sheep</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

This is the mainActivityfile

```
package com.mlx.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    String randomstr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] arrays = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);


        final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i ++ ) {
            randomstr = arrays[i];
        }

        final Button getrandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getrandom);
        getrandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview.setText(randomstr);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now when I run it, it just displays the item "sheep" from on first button click and then it doesn't change, but i want it to change on every press.

Comment: Why do you expect something else from your code? In the listener you always display the same string `randomstr`.

Answer (score 3):

- You must remove the loop because it just assigns the last value of the array in randomstr.
- you have afterwards to define an iterator inside the click method, and update this iterator at each click so you can display the next value

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      Context context = this;
      String randomstr;
      int iterator = 0;

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      String[] arrays = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);


      final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i ++ ) {
          = arrays[i];
      }

      final Button getrandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getrandom);
      getrandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              //Read the current value
              randomstr = arrays[iterator];

              //Display the current value
              textview.setText(randomstr);

              //Increment the iterator to read the next value
              iterator = iterator+1;

              //If we reached the length of the array, we reset the iterator
              if(iterator >= arrays.length) {
                 iterator = 0;
            }
          }
      });
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Great, you're welcome! Please don't forget to up vote / mark the answer as accepted to close the topic! :-)